# Swift Dictionary adding square brackets after key for a value of type [String]

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, alamofire

I have a serializer method that turns my swift objects into dictionaries so that I can send them in http requests.

this particular method is the one giving me the problem

```
class func toDictionary ( _ order: Order ) -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
    return [
        "products" : NSArray(array:order.getProducts()),
        "owning_user" : NSString(string: order.getOwningUser()),
        "restaurant" : NSString(string: order.getRestaurantId())
    ]
}
```

order.getProducts() returns an array of type [String]

When I send this in a http request it gets sent as

```
{"products[]":["...","..."],
 "restaurant":"sdfsdf"
}
```

Obviously my server is expecting products as the key therefore its not getting the proper values.

Any idea why the square brackets are being added?

Note:

My http requests are done via alamofire

EDIT:

Turns out the problem was with alamofire

Please see below for solution

Comment: `toDictionary` returns the correct value (without the extra brackets)? If you convert that dictionary into JSON object too?

Comment: @Larme toDictionary does return a dictionary without the extra brackets yes. I then cant convert that dictionary to a JSON object as Alamofire only accepts parameters in the form of a dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a problem to do with alamofire's encoding when passing a dictionary as a httpBody.

For anyone having the same problem:

solve this by adding the following property to your Alamofire post request

```
encoing: JSONEncoding.default
```

the final request looks as follows

```
Alamofire.request( requestURL, method: .post, parameters: orderJson, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
```

and it yields the following JSON being posted

```
{ restaurant: '580e33ee65b84973ffbc7beb',
  products: [ '580f5cdafaa1067e55be696d' ],
  owning_user: '580e2d174e93b0734e9a04cb'
}
```

As I had originally wanted.

Comment: can you help me I am still facing issue

Comment: My Alamofire POST http body request not working, actually I have array in parameter that's causing the problem I guess

Comment: Any help is appreciate as I stuck in this issue for 2 days

Answer (score 1):

Ok this appears to work here, so I think I need more context as to what your doing different. If this solves your issue, please up vote! Thanks!
Possible issues; you may be have an array within another array? If order.getProducts() already returns an array, don't place it in another. Another option may be to .flatMap it "NSArray(array:order.getProducts()).flatMap {$0}" << will make a single array out of arrays of arrays.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

func toDictionary () -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
    return [
        "products" : NSArray(array:["Paper","Pencil","Eraser"]),
        "owning_user" : NSString(string: "user2976358"),
        "restaurant" : NSString(string: "TacoBell")
    ]
}


let rValue = toDictionary()

let jsonData:Data!
do {
 jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: rValue, options: .prettyPrinted)
    let newString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
    print(newString!)
} catch
{
    print(error)
}
```

The results in the Debug area show this

```
{
  "restaurant" : "TacoBell",
  "products" : [
    "Paper",
    "Pencil",
    "Eraser"
  ],
  "owning_user" : "user2976358"
}
```

Comment: order.getProducts() does return an array yes. But it seems like it may be AlamoFire playing with the strings. As you say there it doesnt infact yield the right json object. Further to the problem if I only have one value in the array, it puts this as a single value in the dictionary rather than an array with a single value inside